# Dynamically sizing bar charts with google graph

Tags: javascript, dynamic, graph

This is just a quick one but I cant find what i need to figure this out. any helps is appreciated.

In the google graphs playground about halfway down (line 48 i think) there is a width variable. It seems to be set as a pixel by default.

Is there any way to set it to be dynamic so the width stretches to the full length of the page?

Or am i better of finding out the full width of the page with jscript and then passing it into the width field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the page width and dynamically generate the width value. The Graph API is pretty brain-dead (yet awesome) and just does what its told.

Comment: Any advice on how to go about this (getting page width) or should i just google it and use whatever seems nicest?

Comment: If you can include jQuery you can put this as an inline javascript. Edit so it works with your chart: $('body').append("<img src='http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png' width='"+$('body').width()+"'>")

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll be able to change the width or height of a chart once it's rendered because it uses an iFrame which you won't have access to, although you could re-draw the chart if the page width/height changes.

Below is is code I use to generate a chart based on it's containing div's width and or height.

This function users [Jquery.com](http://jquery.com/)'s width()/height()

```
<pre>
// Draws Google Chart inside a pre-existing chart_id 
render_chart = function(chart_id, chartType, data, options) {
    // Create and populate the data table.
    var gData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);

    // Special full width over-ride flag
    if(options.width == '*') {
        // Set chart width to it's containing Div's width';
        options.width = $('#'+chart_id).width();
        // Set height equal to width
        if(options.height == 'width') options.height = options.width;
    }

    // Special full height over-ride flag
    if(options.height == '*') {
        // Set chart height to it's containing Div's width';
        options.height = $('#'+chart_id).height();
        // Set width equal to height
        if(options.width == 'height') options.width = options.height;
    }

    // Create and draw the visualization.
    new google.visualization[chartType](document.getElementById(chart_id)).draw(gData, options);
}
</pre>
```